# How to use VBA to extract text in a string between two characters?

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I'm working on a document of press release articles and trying to extract the firm names from this word file to Excel worksheet.

for example: from this short paragraph below, i want to get **MI Developments Inc**

> <sup>AURORA, ON, March 29 /PRNewswire-FirstCall/ - MI Developments Inc. (TSX: MIM.A, MIM.B; NYSE: MIM) ("MID" or the "Company") today.</sup>

At the moment, i found a pattern to identify the name, the name is between“/ -“ and "("

For example, if I only look at the nearest characteristics before and after the name in the context, the name of MI Developments Inc will be shown as flows:

```
/ - MI Developments Inc. (
```

However, I ‘m not sure how to run a right VBA code on word to extract the name of firms to excel worksheet

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a moment to read the guidelines on asking Question in the [Help]. You'll see that this is not a free code-writing or tutorial service. You're expected to have already done basic research and ask very specific, targeted questions about code that's not working. Your question is much too broad.

Comment: Needs more info if you want a general solution

Comment: @CindyMeister @ Tim Williams, I apologize for my reckless post without go through the guidances of Help center, I have edited my post already. Thanks for your advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Microsoft office wildcard searches.
https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Replace-text-using-wildcards-5cda8b1b-2feb-45a6-af0e-824173d3d6e4
http://word.mvps.org/faqs/general/usingwildcards.htm

I got answer from community. Try to tweak with this.

```
Sub demo()
With ActiveDocument
Dim StrOut As String, DocNew As Document
  With .Range
    With .Find
      .ClearFormatting
      .Replacement.ClearFormatting
      .Forward = True
      .Format = False
      .MatchWildcards = True
      .Wrap = wdFindStop
      .Text = "\/ - * \("
      .Replacement.Text = ""
      .Execute
    End With
    Do While .Find.Found
      StrOut = StrOut & Replace(Replace(.Text, "/ - ", ""), " (", "") & vbCr
      .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
      .Find.Execute
    Loop
  End With
End With
'Do whatever yo want to do with strOut.
'I don't have excel experience.
'I generally save it as text and chnge the ext from .txt to .csv which will open ok with excel.
Set DocNew = Documents.Add
With DocNew
  .Range.Text = StrOut
  .SaveAs2 FileName:="C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Desktop\i.txt", _
    FileFormat:=wdFormatText, AddToRecentFiles:=False
  .Close
End With
Set DocNew = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Look up the function [`InStr`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/8460tsh1(v=vs.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) and also:

- [`Mid`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05e63829(v=vs.90).aspx):
- [`Trim`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9wz3dez(v=vs.90).aspx)

---

#### Steps to Follow

1. Use `InStr` to find the first character position of - and (.
2. Work out the number of characters between the two positions.
3. Now use `Mid` to extract the text into another variable.
4. Use `Trim` to get rid of whitespace.

Comment: Thanks alot, very useful ways of dealing with these massive materials

Comment: You are welcome. Would you mind giving me an upvote please? :)

Comment: Yeah，of course. I already gave an upvote, unfortunately, a dialog box pops out stating that:"once you earn 15 rep, your votes can be displayed." Thus i assume the upvote will be shown soon, im still working on getting more reputations. ;)

Comment: OK ... you will get there ... :)